# Modify Code - lookup 2nd Last letter of data in a cell. Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If data in a cell in Column B has a A or B as the **2nd last letter ONLY** - (example of Location G08B1) - Copy that row to another sheet.

I use a modified version of copy row if certain cell has certain word, so not sure how to modify this to what I need.

```
  function CopyAorBLocation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "FORKLIFT" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == copy AorB if 2nd last letter - if not ignore) 
 {
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSS = 
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var tempSheet = s.copyTo(targetSS);
  var targetSheet = targetSS.getSheetByName("ONLINERELOCATION");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  tempSheet.getRange(row, 4, 1, 3).copyTo(target);
```

Hoping this is not too complicated to achieve.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would like to correctly understand about your question. So can I ask you about your question? 1. What is `example of Location G08B1`? 2. What is `event` in your script? 3. What is `if(s.getName() == "FORKLIFT" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == copy AorB if 2nd last letter - if not ignore)`? 4. At your if statement, `r.getColumn() == 7` is used. In this case, when the edit cell is the column "G", the script in the if statement is run. How about this?

Comment: Tanaike - please disregard the code - it was just an example I currently use. have a look at link to spreadsheet with example of what I need.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XtFwY68Gp_YmUsZ2KJcPZOk-d_wCpQ7d4_ENWV6P2MI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you for replying. I couldn't access to the shared Spreadsheet. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: very Sorry Tanaike - Good to go now

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see your shared Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand what you want to do. Can you explain about your goal? By the way, where can I see your current script?

Comment: Tanaike - Can I use Google Translate English to Japanese ? it might be easier ? I will add comments in Japanese for you in a few hrs when I get home. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208020/discussion-between-tom-sawkins-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From the information, I proposed a sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The input and output sample values are the column "B" and the columns "C:D", respectively.
- You want to put the values of column "B" to the column "C" and "D" by the 2nd last character of each value of the column "B".

  - Put the values `###A#` and `###B#` to the column "C".
  - Put the values `###C#` and `###D#` to the column "D".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, the 2nd last character of each value is retrieved by `substring()`.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var srcValues = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  var dstValues = srcValues.map(function([b]) {
    var len = b.length;
    var s = b.substring(len - 2, len - 1).toUpperCase();
    return (s == "A" || s == "B") ? [b, ""] : (s == "C" || s == "D") ? ["", b] : ["", ""];
  });
  sheet.getRange(2, 3, dstValues.length, 2).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- In this sample script, `Sheet1` is used.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your shared Spreadsheet. If the format is different from your shared Spreadsheet, the script might not work. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Tanaike - You have done it again !!!!! - thank you Code worked as expected.

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for quick replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately I will still have a few more questions in the future if thats ok. I am about 75% finished building my Inventory system. thank you

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. If my answer was not useful, I have to modify it.

Comment: I was thanking you for your help so far, I might have some more questions in the future.

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Oh. I could understand about it. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: あなたのすべての助けに感謝します。質問への回答がもう少し必要になるかもしれません